# How to access other websites with Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a website in Django which the users can authenticate into other websites, so my Django website can get some informations from these websites.

For example, if I have an account on Ebay Affiliate Program, I would access my Django website, next I would access my account on Ebay from my Django website, and finally, Django would extract the informations that I need from my Ebay account. Is it possible? If not, could you suggest some solutions?

Additionally, is there a way to store the login details to use later without typing again every time?

Comment: Everything is possible, my friend. However the problem is so broad that it's hard to answer that question. Ebay has its own API (google it), you can use it. And storing data on the Django side is quite easy as well: just read tutorials.

Comment: There are some sites which I can use API, but for those ones that I can't, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

regarding login credentials you can use the `django-allauth` that has a lot of external login options including the ability to fetch data..

I am not sure they have ebay though, but - most sites have an API you can use to get credentials and fetch data on the user. Ebay is one of those.

Even further - a lot of APIs have an open-source implementation that can help you achieve what you want a lot faster.

For example, a quick search in Google found the `django-ebay` package. I don't use it so I don't know about its quality and how easy it is, but you get the idea.

I see in the comments that you wanted to know what can you do with sites that don't have an API - well in that case you will have to use scrapping - which means you impersonate the user in some manner (using automated "server impersonating for instance, like [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/)) and read the data - **BUT** this is commonly **illegal** and/or a **breach of the terms of use** for a lot of sites, so make sure you are allowed to do that first.

Except that, unfortunately, there isn't too much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

- If the website provides an API, use it
- If the website doesn't provide an API don't then contact the website authors, present your use case and kindly ask them to program the API for you.

However sounds like in your case you are doing something which the website owner does not want to co-operate with. Then there are some ways to access the site programmatically

- [Selenium browser based automation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) (run full web browser on the server-side)
- [Mechanize - do raw HTTP GET/POST requests against site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/)

Most big name sites are harneded against bot traffic, so this is sure way to get yourself banned.